# Comparing two Lists of a class without iterating the lists

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

I have a class Abc as below

```
public class Abc {
  int[] attributes;

  Abc(int[] attributes){
    this.attributes = attributes;
  }
}
```

Overriding the `Abc` hash code as below

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 0;
    int multiplier = 1;
    for(int i = attributes.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i++){
        hashCode = hashCode+(attributes[i]*multiplier);
        multiplier = multiplier*10;
    }       
    return hashCode;    
}
```

I am using above class to create a list of objects and I want to compare whether the two lists are equal i.e. lists having objects with same attributes.

```
    List<Abc> list1 ;
     list1.add(new Abc(new int[]{1,2,4}));
     list1.add(new Abc(new int[]{5,8,9}));
     list1.add(new Abc(new int[]{3,4,2}));
   List<Abc> list2;       
     list2.add(new Abc(new int[]{5,8,9}));
     list2.add(new Abc(new int[]{3,4,2}));
      list2.add(new Abc(new int[]{1,2,4}));
```

How can I compare the above two lists with/without iterating over each list . Also is there any better way to override the hashcode , so that two classes having the same attributes(values and order) should be equal.

Comment: you should be overriding the `equals` method rather than the `hashcode`.. when you want to compare objects it should be the equals method that should be overridden..

Comment: As a matter of style, you should always simultaneously override both `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Two objects that are `equals()` to each other have to have the same `hashCode()`, and vice versa. It probably doesn't matter in this small example but I thought I'd make the point anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the function `equals` in your class `Abc`. If you are using an IDE, it can be used to generates something good enough. For example, Eclipse produces the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Abc other = (Abc) obj;
    if (!Arrays.equals(attributes, other.attributes)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

With this `equals` method, you can now check that two instance of `Abc` are equal.

If you want to compare your two lists `list1` and `list2`, unfortunately you can not simply do

```
boolean listsAreEqual = list1.equals(list2); // will be false
```

because that would not only check if the elements in the lists are the same but also if they are in the same order. What you can do is to compare two sets, because in sets, the elements have no order.

```
boolean setAreEqual = new HashSet<Abc>(list1).equals(new HashSet<Abc>(list2)); // will be true.
```

Note that in that case, you should keep your implementation of `hashcode()` in `Abc`, for the `HashSet` to function well. As a general rule, a class that implements `equals` should also implement `hashcode`.

The problem with a `Set` (`HashSet` are `Set`) is that by design it will not contain several objects which are equal with each other. Objects are guaranteed to be unique in a set. For example, if you add a new `new Abc(new int[]{5,8,9})` in the second set, the two sets will still be equal.

If it bothers you then the possible solution is either to compare two lists, but after having sorted them beforehand (for that you have to provide a comparator or implements `compareTo`), or use Guava's [HashMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html), which is an unordered container that can contain the same objects multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Will the hashcode method I have mentioned in the post is correct for the Hashset to function correctly.

Comment: It is correct, that is it conform to the only important rule which is that two objects that are equal will have the same hashcode. You can simplify your implementation by using the utility method `Arrays.hashcode()` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: Thanks ,will use Arrays.hashCode().

Answer (score 0):

Override the equals method to compare objects. As the comments mention, you should be overriding the hashcode method as well when overriding equals method.

By this

> so that two classes having the same attributes(values and order) should be equal.

i think you mean two objects having same attributes.

you can try something like this

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if(!(Object instanceOf Abc)) {
    return false;
  }
  Abc instance = (Abc)o;
  int[] array = instance.attributes;
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if(array[i]!=this.attributes[i]) {
        return false;
      }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** As for the `hashcode` the concept is that when

```
object1.equals(object2)
```

is true, then

```
object1.hashcode()
```

and

```
object2.hashcode()
```

must return the same value. and `hashCode()` of an object should be same and consistent through the entire lifetime of it. so generating hashcode based on the value of its instance variables is not a good option as a different hashcode may be generated when the instance variable value changes.

Comment: If you override equals you should (must) override hash code as well.  See Joshua Bloch.

Comment: @Black Panther Thanks for the reply . I have already overridden the equals method as you have answered . I have given the hashcode in the post to know whether my implementation for the hash code is right or is there any chance of violating the hashcode contract.